# i m tring to create app using goolge maps detected in pubspec.yaml: Error on line 30, column 3: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create an app using google maps with live location, but when i add  some dependencies i got this problem.

````
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

> dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.11
  http: ^0.12.0+1
  json_serializable: ^2.0.2


**dev_dependencies:**
   flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  pedantic: ^1.4.0
  build_runner: ^1.2.7



*flutter:*
  uses-material-design: true ```
````

Comment: this the error that shows detected in pubspec.yaml: Error on line 30, column 3: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the full pubspec.yaml?

It shoud be like:

```
name: myapp
description: My App
version: 1.0.0

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.21+2
```